# emgucv c# high CPU consumption

Tags: c#, cpu, emgucv, frame-rate

My camera : 1920*1080p 30fps
my pc : i5 4gb ram

When i get video stream with c# , pc cpu work with %50 value. This is problem for me.  How can reduce this consumption value. without changing fps.

my code :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    try
    {
        _capture = new VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.3.2/stream/profile1=u");
        _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;

    }
}

private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    Mat frame = new Mat();
    _capture.Retrieve(frame, 0);
    ımageBox1.Image = frame;

}
```

thank you..

Comment: Have you considered using the `Application.Idle` event instead of `_capture.ImageGrabbed` event like [the example](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Camera_Capture_in_7_lines_of_code) shows in their documentation

Comment: sorry But this example uses emgucv 1.5.0 version. i am using emgucv 3.3. because of that my codes are diffirent.